# Can the "$\forall x\in X $" be moved in this statement? "$\Gamma$ satisfiable $\implies \exists v:v(\alpha)=1 \forall \alpha \in \Gamma$".

Tags: logic, notation

Can the "$\forall x\in X $" be moved in this statement? "$\Gamma$ satisfiable $\implies \exists v:v(\alpha)=1  \forall \alpha \in \Gamma$".

I mean, is this the same than to write "$\Gamma$ satisfiable $\implies \exists v: \forall \alpha \in \Gamma\text{ }v(\alpha)=1$"?

Comment: Indeed, it’s always confusing and often ambiguous to have a quantifier at the end. Much better to put all the quantifiers at the beginning, *in the right order*.

Comment: I see, which quantifiers are "commutative"? What is standard to put after the quantifiers: a coma, just a blank?

Comment: Quantifiers don’t commute. I think anybody would be satisfied with commas. In all these things I must defer to someone like @MauroALLEGRANZA, who knows the field.

Comment: Actually, $\forall$ "commutes" with $\forall$ and $\exists$ with $\exists$, but $\forall$ and $\exists$ usually can't be interchanged.

Comment: this is simply a question about first-order logic, not about its metatheory.  and it's bad practice to use so much formalism in the metalanguage.

Comment: Why is that? $ $$ $

Comment: metatheory is just ordinary mathematics, though with formal systems as its subject-matter.

Answer (score 1):

In a formal language, we have to follow the syntactical rules; thus a f-o formula must be written (as usual) with *quantifiers* in front of the sub-formula which is their *scope*.

When we mix symbols and natural language, as in your case, where you are expressing a meta-mathematical fact :

> "if a set of formulae is satisfiable, then there exists a valuation that satisfy all formulae in that set"

we have more freedom, but in any case we have to improve readibility without introducing ambiguities.

Thus, if we want to use : $∃v:v(α)=1, ∀α \in Γ$, we have to be aware that someone may read it as : $∀α \in Γ, ∃v:v(α)=1$.